# How to send url link in the message using Telegram Bot or Show a button to open the URL link

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Message text by Bot as:

Click to Open  [URL](http://www.example.com/)

URL is http://www.example.com/

reference image as:
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is two way to give the option to open the URL in bot-message by the user as:

API endpoint- [https://api.telegram.org/bot{MENTION_YOUR_BOT_TOKEN*}/sendMessage](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7BMENTION_YOUR_BOT_TOKEN*%7D/sendMessage)

API method- GET

1. Show URL in the message

hit the API with this raw JSON data-

```
{
    "chat_id" : MENTION_USER_CHAT_ID*,
    "text" : "Click to Open [URL](http://example.com)",
    "parse_mode" : "markdown"
}
```

2. Show a URL button below the message

hit the API with this raw JSON data-

```
{
    "chat_id" : MENTION_USER_CHAT_ID*,
    "text" : "Click to Open URL",
    "parse_mode" : "markdown",
    "reply_markup" : {
        "inline_keyboard" : [
            [
                {
                    "text" : "Open link",
                    "url" : "http://example.com"
                }
            ]
        ]
   }
}
```

Note: replace * marked variable as per your data.